# Tutorial to create PieChart with compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pie-chart

I try to find a tutorial or some documentation to find how create PieChart graphic in .net compact framework 3.5.

Some body could help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Compact Framework doesn't provide any built-in graphing controls.**

You'll either need to use a 3rd-party component:

- http://www.pocketpccontrols.com/controls/piechart/
- http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/compactchart.aspx
- http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ChartMobileDevices/
- http://www.softwarefx.com/SFXNetProducts/PocketCfxNet/default.aspx

...or custom-draw your own, using the tools provided under the `System.Drawing` namespace. Here are a couple of samples showing how you could draw your own graphic objects in the Compact Framework:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/pocketbargraph.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx